# mysql escape single quote in string without slash?

Tags: mysql

if we use *mysql_real_escape_string()*, it will add slash in string, when we need output, need to strip slashes using *stripslashes()*. How can I add a string with single quote or double quote without adding slashes in mysql

Eg: `$name = mysql_real_escape_string("genelia d'souza");
$result = mysql_query(" insert into user (id,name) value ( 1,'$name') ");`

```
id | name
--------------------
1  | genelia d\'souza
```

Want like this

```
id | name
--------------------
1  | genelia d'souza
```

is there any way to avoid adding slash before inserting and strip slashes before outputting???

Comment: Try this for adding slashes
<?php
$str = addslashes('What does "yolo" mean?');
echo($str);
?>

Comment: Might me issue at the time of same data so you store like this way and at the time of display remove slashes..

Comment: Use prepared statements and placeholders.  You should not be manually escaping and building queries like this. It's a deprecated practice.